# Channel_not_found: authed_user cannot post a message to a channel via Slack API

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I'm trying to post a message on a channel a user belongs via the Slack Api as an authed_user.

here is the flow:

1. User gives permissions with scopes `'chat:write,channels:write,channels:history'`
2. I receive a token along with some more information from Slack that looks like `xoxp-122474-a bunch of numbers`
3. I create a Slack Client with the token and sends a request with:

```js
 const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');

 const client = new WebClient(token.access_token);

 await client.chat.postMessage({
      channel: channelId, // = Something similar to C02E2K5CCUZ
      as_user: true,
      text: "here is some text",
    });
```

I get an error from the slack API, 'channel_not_found' but I checked the channel does exists + the user is in the channel.

What should I do to make this work? Am I missing anything?

Thank you !

Comment: How did you find the channel ID?

Comment: I save it earlier on, but also tried hard coding it to make sure it was the right one

Comment: Like is there a way to verify that your channel Id is correct? Because it sounds like that's the issue.

Comment: Yep I tried looking at the slack channel Id manually and they seem to match

Comment: No idea. this all works for me. More docs here: https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#message-sending

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that error is a red herring. The `as_user` parameter might be messing you up. That parameter can only be used for legacy apps. You can still use `chat.postMessage` but make sure you are also requesting the `[chat:write.customize][1]` scope. You will then be able to customize the posting user by defining the `username` and `icon_url`parameters in your API call.